# Listchars showing end of line when there is no newline char

Tags: list, listchars

Create a new text file with notepad, type in 'hello world' and do not press enter at the end. Save the file.

This file has no newline character at the end of the file. Hex editor confirms this.

Yet opening the file in Vim, and turning on `set list`, the `listchars` shows the eol character. Why? Bug?

I've googled and I understand why Vim chooses to automatically write eol chars, and that I can turn that off using `set nofixeol`. But that is irrelevant to this.

The question I have is:

How do I get Vim to only display newline chars that actually exist in the file? Clearly `listchars` does not do this

Comment: you cannot. the 'list' option is an indication where the line **ends** not that it is terminated by a *line-separator* character.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt the file ends, not the line

Comment: of course the *line ends* when the *file ends* :)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt not according to `more` or `cat` as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/312601

Comment: yes and? As mentioned on the ticket, this is the vi compatible behaviour. the list character is mainly an indication where the line ends visually, independently of whether there exists or does not exist a line termination character.

Comment: indeed, updated my comment on the ticket to add new suggestion

Answer (score 1):

From a quick google, the answer to my question is: It is not possible:

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6119